# How to find types in IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> returned by PetaPoco.Database.Query<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, dynamic, types, petapoco, expandoobject

I'd like to find out at runtime all the types in an ExpandoObject.

Here's some exploratory code:

```
using PetaPoco;

...

var data = _d.Query<dynamic>(_script);
IDictionary<string, object> hood = (IDictionary<string, object>)data.First();
var wow = hood.Values.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.GetType().ToString());
```

The where method politely steps over the null values in the returned ExpandoObject...  hardly a solution as it relies on a row even being returned in the first place.

Is there a better way to query what PetaPoco.Database learns as it builds the ExpandoObject?

(The fallback is to query the database again for its schema objects.)

Answer (score 0):

Take the data source creator.cs from [this](http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-from-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary) blog add a few overloads for a `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. This will ilEmit new types that you can explore, or perhaps save out as an assembly.
Or grab the download directly from http://www.bodurov.com/files/DataSourceCreator.cs.zip

This is the method you'd be using on the thing that comes out of PetaPoco

```
public static IEnumerable ToDataSource(this IEnumerable<IDictionary> list)
```

but make copy pasta of the code adding overloads with the near exactly same implementations but the signature

```
public static IEnumerable ToDataSource(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> list)
```

so then your code adjusted for this would be

```
var hood=data.Cast<IDictionary<string,object>>().ToDataSource();
```